# Why after tried vpn download speed gets lower?

Tags: linux, vpn, internet, linux-mint

I tried failure attempt to connect to a free VPN provider using Linux Mint 18. After that I was unable to buffer songs effectively but now as I deleted Ethernet connection and tried new one, browsing speed is better than before but downloading speed suck. Why am I having this issue? Should I reset Firefox ?

Comment: If you are routing all of your traffic through the vpn then yes, things are going to slow down.  Best learn more about how vpns work.

Comment: Though I couldn't connected to VPN ? Just failure attempt.

Comment: You didn't say that.  Try editing your question with more details.  I doubt anyone will be able to answer your question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a free VPN provider which would probably be the first issue with your overall bandwidth speed.

When using a free VPN provider you are usually going to be limited to the amount of available bandwidth you can use.  Free servers can also suffer from having to many users at certain times in the day.

You may want to signup to a well known VPN service that has good reviews for fast bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

IT's suppose to be slow down you regular speed, Because VPN route your traffic to different tunnel to encrypt your data. here is [how VPN Encryption works](https://www.beencrypted.com/vpn-encryption-guide/)

Comment: I know why speed gets down while working with VPN. But my question is "why it is even though I had failure attempt with VPN ?" I couldn't connect VPN successfully , so as I delete VPN and tried without it then I've face problem like lower speed. But now its solved. I just delete ethernet connection from my mate network manager and tried with new one. And problem solved. Thank you.